# How do I get to subfolders in a bash script that takes an argument?

Tags: linux, bash

In a bash script I wrote, I would like to copy files with the `.txt` extension. But I could not include sub-folders with `-R`. How can I solve this?

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
for arg in "$@"
do
    kopya="kopya$n.txt"
    cp -R -- "$arg" "$kopya"
    n=$[ n + 1 ]
done
```

Comment: `$[...]` is an obsolete syntax; use `n=$((n+1))` instead.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It looks like you want to cp every path below a given directory into one file.  The net effect is to copy the last file.  Do you want to concatenate all of the files recursively into one file?

Comment: For example, I want to copy files with the ".txt" extension in the test folder. But if there are subfolders in the test folder and if there are ".txt" files in these folders, include them in the copy process.

Comment: @chepner If you're going to go there, then...  `(( n++ ))`

Comment: @Jack `$((...))` is standard; `(( ... ))` is not.

Comment: @chepner `$((...))` tries to RUN the result, which is NOT what you want.  `n=1; $((n++))` just says "bash: 1: command not found...".  `((n++))` increments `n`.

Comment: @Jack You are confusing `$((...))` with `$(...)`, or you think I was recommending `$((n++))`, which I was not.

Comment: @chepner Please post link to standard (ANSI or ISO).

Comment: `$((...))` is part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `find` to get the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
for arg in "$@"
do
  kopya="kopya$n.txt"
  find . -name "$arg" -exec cp {} "$kopya" \;
  (( n++ ))
done
```

Comment: This won't work right because it only increments `$n` between arguments, not when multiple files are matched by a single argument. Also, I'm not clear if the arguments are supposed to be name patterns to search for under the current directory (which this assumes) or directories to be searched, or what. The question is unclear on this.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but there is no indication that the O.P. wants that behavior.  However, the O.P is running `cp -R`, indicating "under the current directory."  For that behavior, he could do `for file in $( find . -name "$arg" ); do cp "$file" "kopya$n.txt"; ((n++)); done`